# Optionally exclude some dependencies when `pip install`ing

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, setuptools, setup.py

`setuptools` provides, as is often used, a way to specify optional dependencies with [`extras_require`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html?highlight=extras#optional-dependencies). Is there a way to do the opposite? That is, to have

```
pip install mypackage
```

install a full set of dependencies, but to have something like

```
pip install mypackage[core]
```

or

```
pip install --core-option mypackage
```

only install a limited set of core dependencies? It doesn’t have to be like `extras_require`, just some way to specify in the pip install that only core dependencies are required.

(For some packages, breaking backwards compatibility in terms of installation is a difficult choice, especially when most users want all of the dependencies. Nevertheless, some users can need to avoid heavy or broken dependencies that are not required for core functions.)

Comment: Apparently this has been discussed at length on python forums: https://discuss.python.org/t/adding-a-default-extra-require-environment/4898

Answer (score 1):

If a lib is dependent it means your code needs it and cannot work without it so I don't think this is possible with a flag.

So I would keep a `requirements.txt` in root for the core functionality and an `optional-requirements.txt` next to it.

Together with a short guide in the `readme.md` to use `pip install requirements.txt` to get the core and `pip install optional-requirements.txt` to get additional stuff that isn't necessary for the code to run. Like better debugging.

I would strongly recommend to put in the readme what's different if you have or have not installed the optional packages.

Comment: This is not a bad idea — I would have prefered something that works in one line with `pip install` (even from PyPI), but given [discussion on Python forums](https://discuss.python.org/t/adding-a-default-extra-require-environment/4898) it sounds like workarounds are the only option, and this one prevents a lot of manual `pip install something something-else`